# Laplace transform of Heaviside function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}0 ,&  t < 4 \\t^{2}-8t+20 ,& t \ge 4\end{cases}$$

The answer is $\frac{e^{-4s}(4s^{2}+2)}{s^{3}}$, but don't know the steps to get to it. Would like some guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $F(s)=\mathcal L\left\{ f(t)\right\}$. Recall the properties

1. **Frequency-domain general derivative**
   $$\mathcal L\left\{t^{n} f(t)\right\}=  (-1)^{n} F^{(n)}(s)$$
2. **Time shifting**   $$\mathcal L\left\{f(t - a) u(t - a) \right\}=  e^{-as} F(s)$$

and observe that your function is
$$
f(t)=(t^2−8t+20)u(t-4)=[(t-4)^2+4]u(t-4)
$$
and $\mathcal L\left\{u(t)\right\}=\frac{1}{s}=U(s)$.

So you have
$$
\begin{align}
F(s)&=\mathcal L\left\{(t-4)^2u(t-4)\right\}+\mathcal L\left\{4u(t-4)\right\}\\
&=(-1)^2U''(s)e^{-4s}+4\,U(s)\,e^{-4s}\\
&=\frac{2}{s^3}e^{-4s}+\frac{4}{s}e^{-4s}\\
&=\frac{e^{-4s}(4s^2+2)}{s^3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal L(f)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\int_4^\infty(t^2-8t+20)e^{-st}\,dt$$ The reason that I can write the integral like this is that $f(t)=0$ for $t\leq 4$, so this region doesn't contribute to the integral. Continuing, $$\mathcal L(f)=\int_4^\infty t^2e^{-st}\,dt-8\int_4^\infty te^{-st}\,dt+20\int_4^\infty e^{-st}\,dt.$$
These integrals can be solved using integration by parts.